# How are timezone / daylight saving changes handled in launchd so that job is consistently executed at specific time of day?

Tags: macos, jobs, job-scheduling, launchd, launch-agent

How can I ensure my launch agent / scheduled job always runs at 20:30 UTC? This should be independent of

- where the computer is located
- daylight savings changes
- current server timezone,
- etc

I know there is a way to schedule jobs via the start calendar interval, but I'm not sure it takes the above considerations into account. Whereas with cron, you can set TZ="UTC".

```
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Weekday</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>8</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Weekday</key>
        <integer>2</integer>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>8</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Weekday</key>
        <integer>3</integer>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>8</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Weekday</key>
        <integer>4</integer>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>8</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Weekday</key>
        <integer>5</integer>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>8</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Thank you!